# GIT Renaming a branch and keeping all commit history

Tags: git, version-control

I have a question regarding renaming a branch in git. I created a local branch `dev` and pushed branch to remote. I did lots of work on the `dev` branch and am updating remote branch regularly.

Now I want to change the name of the branch from `dev` to `development`. I know how to rename a branch in GIT.

My question is like if I rename the branch, does commit history to the `dev`-branch will be lost or not? If yes, how do i keep my commit-history?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Now I want to change the name of the branch from dev to development, I know how to rename branch in GIT. My question is like if I rename the branch, does commit history to the dev-branch will be lost or not? If yes, how do i keep my commit-history?

You can simply create a new branch from your `dev` branch, and then delete the `dev` branch. The new branch will be a copy of your existing branch, I often do this to guard against breaking a branch when rebasing, or merging.

Here's a sample output:

```
# Normal state, for me at least
$ git branch
=> master
# Get into your dev branch.
$ git checkout dev
=> dev
# Now we make a new branch `development' based on `dev'
$ git checkout -b development
=> development
$ git branch -d dev
```

You can always check the `git log` before the last step, if you prefer. But all branches in Git are just special tagged references. Creating `development` from `dev` doesn't duplicate everything, so you don't waste any space by keeping it.

Answer (score 5):

As per [man pages](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html): `git branch -move` - move/rename a branch **and** the corresponding reflog.

Comment: I believe this should be `git branch --move`, with two dashes

Comment: but this renames local branch not remote ?