# Rename GitHub Branch and keep commit History

Tags: git, github, branch, branching-and-merging

I'm working on a project that has been messed up a little bit on Github.
Currently the `master` branch is an old not used branch (its written in angular with mdl instead of angular material). the actual project is now in another branch.

Current status 2 Branches :

- `master` (which is not used, but shouldnt be deleted)
- `protoype` (which we want to rename to `master`, without loosing the commit history)

I googled a lot, but couldnt find an appropriate solution, since we dont want to loose the commit history of the prototype branch, we cannot simply create a new branch and push it in the new branch (at least thats how i understood it).

So, what im looking for, is to move, rename or whatever the actual prototype branch without loosing the commit history

Wanted status:

- original `prototype` branch  renamed to `master` branch including the commit history
- original `master` branch  renamed to `old` branch which holds the (optionally including the commit history)

I'm be thankful for any help!

**UPDATE:**

of course i found many blogs and links which described how to rename a branch. but i didnt find out if the commit history will still be available, because it sounded like youd just move the current state of the branch into a new branch. But now i just found [this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23604935/git-renaming-a-branch-and-keeping-all-commit-history) which answers my question! So yes, moving a branch with `git branch -m` also copies the commit history!

thanks for the help!

But still one question remains: What is the difference between these two answers? Is the Outcome the very same, or is there a reason why i would prefer one over the other?

[Answer 1:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23605062/7927273)

```
# Normal state, for me at least
$ git branch
=> master

# Get into your dev branch.
$ git checkout dev
=> dev

# Now we make a new branch `development' based on `dev'
$ git checkout -b development
=> development
$ git branch -d dev
```

[Answer 2:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30590238/7927273)

```
#rename the local branch to the new name
git branch -m old_name new_name 

#delete the old branch on remote - where <remote> is eg. origin
git push <remote> --delete old_name

#push the new branch to remote         
git push <remote> new_name
```

Comment: Could you please reopen the question?